# Install cp2k in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am facing this error when instal cp2k in Cygwin.

```
223 | #error -ffast-math (GCC) or -hfpN (N>0, Cray) can lead to wrong results and numerical instabilities and are therefore no longer supported
      |  1~~~~
Error: #error -ffast-math (GCC) or -hfpN (N>0, Cray) can lead to wrong results and numerical instabilities and are therefore no longer supported
make[3]: *** [/cygdrive/c/My_stuff/5-Sotwares/cp2k-7.1/cp2k-7.1/Makefile:466: environment.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/cygdrive/c/My_stuff/5-Sotwares/cp2k-7.1/cp2k-7.1/Makefile:134: all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/cygdrive/c/My_stuff/5-Sotwares/cp2k-7.1/cp2k-7.1/Makefile:123: sopt] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: all] Error 2
```

Please help me tp overcome this issue.

Comment: add the full configure and make invocation. At first glance it seems you chose a configuration not supported.

Comment: I looked at the cp2k installation script. It seems one of the monster math application that tries to build by themself a ton of mathematical libraries. It already fails to detect a lot of already installed math libraries. Be aware that the effort to make it running under cygwin seems very high and time consuming.